# Watch file change by FileSystemWatcher does not work on network drive

Tags: .net, powershell, filesystemwatcher, robocopy

I created a powershell script using FileSystemWatcher. This script watch a network drive and if any event runs robocopy.

For example:
Every time a file is created, changed or deleted the robocopy is executed.

However, FileSystemWatcher is not detecting "change" events, but only "create" and "delete" events.

When I test FileSystemWatcher by watch a local directory the change, create, and delete events work normally.

This is the code:

```
$folderBack = '\\network_drive\' # Enter the root path you want to monitor.
$filterBack = '*.*'  # You can enter a wildcard filter here.

$fswBack = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folderBack, $filterBack -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $true;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'}


Register-ObjectEvent $fswBack Changed -SourceIdentifier FileChangedBack -Action {
$name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
$timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
Start-Sleep 5
robocopy  \\network_drive\ G:\local\ /E /MIR /DST /FFT /XO /XJ /MT:8 /R:3 /W:10 /Z /NP /NDL /XF ~* *.TMP /LOG:robocopy.log
Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore white
Out-File -FilePath c:\scripts\filechange\outlog.txt -Append -InputObject "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"}

Register-ObjectEvent $fswBack Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreatedBack -Action {
    $nameBack = $EventBack.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $changeTypeBack = $EventBack.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $timeStampBack = $EventBack.TimeGenerated
        robocopy robocopy  \\network_drive\ G:\local\ /E /MIR /DST /FFT /XO /XJ /MT:8 /R:3 /W:10 /Z /NP /NDL /XF ~* *.TMP /LOG:robocopy.log
    Write-Host "The file '$nameBack' was $changeTypeBack at $timeStampBack" -fore green
    Out-File -FilePath c:\scripts\filechange\outlog.txt -Append -InputObject "The file '$nameBack' was $changeTypeBack at $timeStampBack"}

Register-ObjectEvent $fswBack Deleted -SourceIdentifier FileDeletedBack -Action {
    $nameBack = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $changeTypeBack = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $timeStampBack = $Event.TimeGenerated
    robocopy robocopy  \\network_drive\ G:\local\ /MIR /DST /FFT /XO /XJ /MT:8 /R:3 /W:10 /Z /NP /NDL /XF ~* *.TMP /LOG:robocopy.log
    Write-Host "The file '$nameBack' was $changeTypeBack at $timeStampBack" -fore red
    Out-File -FilePath c:\scripts\filechange\outlog.txt -Append -InputObject "The file '$nameBack' was $changeTypeBack at $timeStampBack"}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried mapping the network location first?

Comment: Is this *really* the code you're trying to run? (`robocopy robocopy `?)

Comment: Mike Sherrill 'Cat Recall' That part was incorrect. I entered twice. But I identified the problem.

I had to add the "Renamed":Register-ObjectEvent $fswBack Renamed-SourceIdentifier FileRenamedBack -Action {
    $nameBack = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $changeTypeBack = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $timeStampBack = $Event.TimeGenerated